# Independent filtering fields on a table generated with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my Angular project I have a table generated with `ng-repeat`, which is supposed to be filtered through four independent fields as you can see on the picture below:

[image: Table header]

My problem is, how do I make it so that whatever I type on one of this query fields does not interfere with the others? e.g.: typing a PROJECT NAME on the PROJECTS SUPPORT column will still filter the table as expected, but it shouldn't.

I guess what I want is to have individual scopes for each column, while still having a given row disappear whenever one of the filters is activated.

This is the code that generates the table below the table headers and input fields:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in page2ctrl.projects | filter:query.name | filter:query.budget | filter:query.period | filter:query.partners">
    <td>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="page2ctrl.projects[$index].isSelected">
            <p><span></span><p>
        </label>
    </td>
    <td><p><strong>{{item.name}}</strong></p></td>
    <td><p>{{item.budget}}</p></td>
    <td><p>{{item.startDate}}</p></td>
    <td><p>{{item.partners}}</p></td>
</tr>
```

How do I "individualize" the filter queries?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this using the object form of the expression. For example, the filter by name would look like this:

```
filter:{ name: query.name }
```

I'm not 100% sure that will work as I haven't tried that particular approach myself. On the other hand, you can definitely do it with a predicate function or custom filter.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 0):

Your filters are all just strings. So the filter does not know, on which key to filter. Specify a key on each filter to clarify what key each filter should filter on. Like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in page2ctrl.projects | filter: { name: query.name } | filter: { budget: query.budget } | filter: { startDate: query.period } | filter: { partners: query.partners }">
    <td>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="page2ctrl.projects[$index].isSelected">
            <p><span></span><p>
        </label>
    </td>
    <td><p><strong>{{item.name}}</strong></p></td>
    <td><p>{{item.budget}}</p></td>
    <td><p>{{item.startDate}}</p></td>
    <td><p>{{item.partners}}</p></td>
```